# How to configure Magento2 to use selenium_hub in a Docker environment

Tags: docker, ftf, selenium

I am struggling to get the selenium hub docker to work with Magento2. I have used it in other frameworks like Django, but I'm struggling to make the connection in Magento2. I'm working on top of https://github.com/meanbee/docker-magento2 as a starting point.

Things I've tried to do to get some more information:

- I can enter the CLI container and curl http://selenium_hub:4444/wd/hub/ to get a JSON response so I know the domain is resolving correctly.
- I tried using just the firefox standalone container but I got the same error.
- I can access the grid console from the host machine, so the containers are running.

Using the following server configuration I get an error

## Error

`The Selenium Server is not active on host http://selenium_hub/wd/hub/ at port 4444.`

## config.xml

```
<server>
    <item name="selenium"
          type="default"
          browser="Mozilla Firefox"
          browserName="firefox"
          host="http://selenium_hub/wd/hub/"
          port="4444"
          seleniumServerRequestsTimeout="90"
          sessionStrategy="shared">
       <desiredCapabilities>
          <browserName>firefox</browserName>
          <platform>ANY</platform>
       </desiredCapabilities>
    </item>
</server>
```

## docker-compose.yml (selenium containers)

```
  selenium_hub:
      container_name: selenium_hub
      image: selenium/hub
      ports:
        - "4444:4444"

  selenium_chrome:
    container_name: selenium_chrome
    image: selenium/node-chrome-debug
    environment:
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=selenium_hub
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444
    ports:
      - "5900:5900"
    depends_on:
      - selenium_hub

  selenium_firefox:
    container_name: selenium_firefox
    image: selenium/node-firefox-debug
    environment:
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=selenium_hub
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444
    ports:
      - "5901:5900"
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
      - selenium_hub
```

I'm still new to Selenium and Magento2, so any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### Follow-Up

Specifying only the host `selenium_hub` as opposed to `http://selenium_hub/wd/hub/` proceeded with the connection, but resulted in a new error: `Fatal error: Uncaught PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: Session [window] not available and is not among the last 1000 terminated sessions.`

Either way, this new problem is no longer related to this question.